# Digest authentication in Windows Store app using HttpClient (C#)

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-store-apps, dotnet-httpclient

I'm struggling with this problem for a week.
I have to use API with Digest authentication in Windows Store App, but while I'm using this code I get System.ArgumentNullException in this line of code:

```
HttpHandler.Credentials = credCache;
```

Here is rest of code:

```
var credCache = new CredentialCache();
credCache.Add(new Uri("https://myserverIP/api"),"Digest",new NetworkCredential("mylogin", "mypassword") );
var HttpHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
HttpHandler.Credentials = credCache;
var httpClient = new HttpClient(HttpHandler);
var answer = await httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri("https://myserverIP/api/?function=someKindOfFunction"));
answer.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I copied that exact code into a project and it works fine (although of course the `GetAsync` fails due to invalid URI).

Comment: Okey, I used now VS 2013 instead of 2015RC and it's working now. :)

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix to your issue is to use `credCache.GetCredentials()` instead of just `credCache` when assigning a value to HttpHandler. Credentials as such:

```
var credCache = new CredentialCache();
credCache.Add(new Uri("https://myserverIP/api"),"Digest",new NetworkCredential("mylogin", "mypassword") );
var HttpHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
HttpHandler.Credentials = credCache.GetCredential(new Uri("https://myserverIP/api"), "Digest");
```

This works without the `ArgumentNullException`.

Hope this helps.

Thanks,
Sid